# SQLAlchemy: How to filter on a joined table without importing the model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Say I have two models, ModelA and ModelB.

They're connected via a 1:n relationship, e.g. ModelA can have many ModelB associated to it. A normal `relationship()` is defined within SQLalchemy and this does work well in general. The problem occurs when I need to do some more complex queries. Lets say, I want to return all ModelB entries, which associated ModelA entry has a particular attribute. What I did so far is:

```
return db.query(ModelB)\
            .filter(
                ModelB.user_id == user_id,
                ModelB.accepted == True
            )\
            .join(ModelB.modela_relationship)\
            .filter(
                ModelB.modela_relationship.attribute1 == some_value,
                ModelB.modela_relationship.date > datetime.now()
            )\
            .all()
```

I explicitly want to use this form of relationship joining and not defining an `aliased` model as I'd need to import the other model for this to work. The reason I don't want to import the model is that this leads to circular imports, as ModelA would require ModelB for a query and ModelB would require ModelA.

This code above yields an error though, which reads:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with ModelB.modela_relationship has an attribute 'attribute1'
```

How would I do this query (get all results filtered by a joined value) without the need to import the model in SQLalchemy?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible in the ORM. Tbh I think if you're got circular imports you should just refactor your code, I tend to keep 3 python files for each section of database tables, 1 for python utils (parsers and sorting, no SQL stuff), one for model schema defs (database models defined here) and one for helper funcs (complex queries and population functions etc). This way, the imports only ever go up the chain and circular imports is never an issue. I also always know exactly where everything is when reviewing things later or trying to remember function names etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sad to hear its likely not possible to do that with the ORM. I have these functions in the same file as they're methods of the model class and therefore can access `self` attributes where neccessary

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll wait 1-2 days before accepting it. For now I worked around it by using local imports, as I really only need that import in the method that does the DB query. Its not a nice solution but I have the feeling, SQLAlchemy has no really nice solution to work around these import problems.

Comment: I've resorted to that as well in the past, until I had time to refactor it. You don't have to accept it at all if it isn't what you're after XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leading on from my comment:

If you're desperate to have the function as a method on the schema, something a bit more complex that you could do is import both ModelA and ModelB into a new file and then inherit from the model into a new definition like this:

```py
from .filea import ModelA
from .fileb import ModelB
from . import db

class ModelBExtra(ModelB):
  __mapper_args__ = {
      "polymorphic_identity": "model_b_extra"
  }

  def myfunc(self):
    return db.query(ModelB).join(
              ModelB.modela_relationship
            ).filter(
                ModelB.user_id == user_id,
                ModelB.accepted == True,
                ModelA.attribute1 == some_value,
                ModelA.date > datetime.now()
            ).all()
```

which gives you the method on what is essentially the same table, and you just import that into where you need it instead.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/inheritance.html

Note that this uses the same underlying table within the SQL database, 'model_b'. It's just declared to SQLAlchemy under a different name because SQLAlchemy can't have schema definitions with the same name. I like to use this occasionally to compartmentalise code and methods to only places where they're needed and maintain that import chain in only one direction as I mentioned in the comment.

I know this isn't really an answer to the exact question, but I can't post code snippets in comments.